# Make a wordpress post from an iOS app

Tags: php, ios, wordpress

New iOS developer here. I'm looking to build an app that uses a Wordpress database to populate a news feed, and I've found a good amount of info about grabbing posts from Wordpress but nothing about posting FROM the app TO the database. I know that the code can't be written here, but I was hoping someone knew where I could find how to do this or point me in the right direction. I planned on writing all of my new code in Swift also. Thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to interact with Wordpress is by activating the jetpack api. You can then do almost anything you want. See the full documentation here: https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/

Reading data is easy. you only have to call the correct URL. If you wan to see a sample (written in swift) then have a look at:
https://github.com/evermeer/AlamofireJsonToObjects/blob/master/AlamofireJsonToObjectsTests/WordpressTest.swift

If you want to make updates, then you need to use Oauth2. Here are some libraries that could help with that: https://cocoapods.org/?q=oauth